# Still getting password prompt after configuring ssh keys

Tags: linux, ssh, key, authorized-keys

I am trying to connect to a remote server without a password and i followed the instructions on this link exactly (http://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/1626/Using+SSH+keys+on+your+server) , I also checked the sshd_config file

```
 SAAuthentication yes
 PubkeyAuthentication yes
 AuthorizedKeysFile      %h/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

However i still get password prompt when i try to log in.
Any help ?

Comment: Can you give us a listing of your .ssh directory on the server? cd ~/.ssh; ls -al

Comment: You can use ssh -vv to debug trace your ssh connection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check for your ~/.ssh directory and/or id_rsa/id_dsa file permissions.
Your ~/.ssh directory should be 700 and your private key files should be 600.

Answer (score 1):

This is simple problem due to ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file permission. By default the mode will be set to 664 when you create the file manually. Change the mode to 600 and you can login without password

```
sudo chmod 700 ~/.ssh
sudo chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Now try ssh into the server

Answer (score 0):

The security log on your system (e.g. /var/log/secure) will often help you in determining what it objects to in using your keys. Please check that log for some clues.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: The ssh key configuration (listed in the link in the question) seemed pretty thorough and complete and should have solved the user's problem. But it didn't and his question was "Any help?" So I thought debugging help would be an appropriate answer. Too many answers are in comments on this site.

Comment: debugging help is definitely helpful. But what your have offered is only that: help, not a solution. It isn't an answer, so it shouldn't be posted as one.